# Markowitz portfolio risk with PV01 instead of variance

Tags: risk, bond, modern-portfolio-theory, markowitz

As the PV01 ($= dpdy \times notional$) of a bond is a measure of its risk, as well as its price return variance, could we measure the risk of a bonds portfolio with the Markovitz portfolio variance formula, but substituting variance by the PV01 of each bond?

ie using $risk = {\sigma}^T \times \rho \times \sigma$ with $\sigma$ the vector of bonds PV01 instead of the vector of bonds variance (and $\rho$ the correlation matrix).

Also can the raw PV01 be used, or the PV01 weight ($= PV01 / \Sigma PV01$)? If using the weight, how can it differentiate between a small portfolio and a very large portfolio, that would have the same bonds proportion, but obviously not bearing the same risk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\rho$ needs to be the correlation matrix of *bond yields* and you also need to scale by the bond yield variances.

All the dv01 scaling does is change the risk variables from price to yield.